# how to retrieve data in tree based table in sql

Tags: php, mysql

### A parent-child relation table like

```
    
id  name    parent-id
1   x   0
2   y   0
3   z   0
4   a   1
5   b   2
6   c   1
7   d   4
8   e   4
```

### i wish to know total number of children of each item so that output look like as below

```
id  name    parent-id   total-child
1   x   0   2
2   y   0   1
3   z   0   0
4   a   1   2
5   b   2   0
6   c   1   0
7   d   4   0
8   e   4   0
```

### please suggest me sql query to achieve this one

Comment: Please include your attempts to solve this issue yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,
name, 
(select count(*) from table t2 where t2.parent-id=t1.id) as child-count
from table t1
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response, But sir, there is only one table in which all the parents and children and children of children are listed Regards...

Comment: @DilverSingh His query is only using one table (named `table`), but it sub-selects to count the children. This should work, just add the ParentId column if you want it.

Comment: Yes, it's as mackan states. t1 and t2 are aliases.

Comment: Thanks Çağatay Gürtürk , stakoverflow and  every one for resolving the question

Comment: @ Çağatay Gürtürk , i will mark it accepted as soon as i will get enough reputation for this....